# Triple boot Win 7, Ubuntu 12.04, Fedora 16

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I have an HP with a 160GB SSD Primary drive and a 500 GB Secondary drive.  I shrank the 500 GB partition to create space to install Ubuntu 12.04 and Fedora 16.

I started by following this tutorial [how-to-triple-boot-fedora-15-ubuntu-11-04-and-windows-7](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/31/how-to-triple-boot-fedora-15-ubuntu-11-04-and-windows-7/)

The only noticeable difference that I found was that I had to create the boot entry for Fedora as GRUB 2.  After installing Fedora and adding the entry to the windows boot loader Fedora launched fine.

I then installed Ubuntu 12.04 and instructed the installer to place Grub in the /boot partition that I made for Ubuntu.  After the install completed I made another windows boot entry for Ubuntu.

Now when I try to launch Fedora I am brought to the Ubuntu grub loader and I can't figure out how to get Grub to detect the Fedora installation.

Do I only need one /boot partition since both distros use Grub2? Or because I used LVM per the tutorial Grub2 can't detect the other distro?

I'm basically a linux noob but I do have a little experience with Ubuntu.

Output from fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x14df4121

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   725110783   362554368    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2   *   725110784   726134783      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sdb3       726134784   850939903    62402560   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sdb4       850941950   976771071    62914561    5  Extended
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sdb5       850941952   851916799      487424   83  Linux
/dev/sdb6       851918848   863635455     5858304   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb7       863637504   883167231     9764864   83  Linux
/dev/sdb8       883169280   976771071    46800896   83  Linux
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Jeremie

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 2):

You only need to install a bootloader (grub) once. It will then automatically detect and all you to boot all the OSes on your machine.

If you wanted to do a clean install of grub, but into the ubuntu liveCD and try this, replacing /dev/sda1 with the partition that has ubuntu on it:

> sudo su
>
> mkdir /mnt/root
>
> mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt/root
>
> mount -t proc none /mnt/root/proc
>
> mount -o bind /dev /mnt/root/dev
>
> mount -o bind /sys /mnt/root/sys
>
> chroot /mnt/root /bin/bash
>
> sudo grub-install /dev/sda
>
> sudo update-grub