# Triple boot problem with Windows 7, Ubuntu 12.04 & Fedora 17

Tags: boot, fedora, dual-boot

I just installed Fedora 17 after Ubuntu 12.04, But now I can't boot into any of 2 linux, I also have windows 7 installed and I can boot to it, I edited boot with EasyBCD.

During installation of Fedora 17 I used standard creating partition and used Separate "/boot" , "/", "Swap" , "Home" for Fedora 17,
Is this fixable? or I have to reinstall 2 OS?

Also Is possible to share one "Swap" partition?

And I am on Ubuntu live cd.
Thanks for any guides.

Comment: Did you installed Fedora 17 on Free Space or you allowed the installer to choose for its own.Also take a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/131825/triple-boot-win-7-ubuntu-12-04-fedora-16)

Comment: I installed on free space, I manually partitioned. also Before asking this question, I saw this link, but "sudo su" command send an error = unable to resolve host ubuntu-studio.

Comment: Please open a new question about the swap partition.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your GRUB  is corrupted.I have myself also a triple (Vista, Ubuntu 11.04 and Ubuntu 12.04).   Boot with the boot CD and let  fix it automatically. Try to repair  the GRUB it with the boot-repair CD.  You can look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to get my system working with Windows 7, Fedora 17 and Ubuntu 12 installed (in that order). During the Ubuntu installation, I made sure not to over-write the master boot record. Hence I used the Fedora grub 2.

I think that grub2 magically looks through the mounted file systems looking for OSs that it can boot; hence you need to make sure they are mounted.

```
# mkdir /mnt1  (create mount point in Fedora / directory)
# mkdir /mnt2
# mkdir /mnt3 
# mount /sda1 /mnt1  (mount the windows partition)
# mount /sda8 /mnt2  (mount the ubuntu / partition)
# mount /sda6 /mnt3  (mount the ubuntu /boot partition; I don't know if this is necessary)
# partprobe (I am not sure if this was needed)
# grub2-install /dev/sda
Installation finished. No error reported.
# grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.3.7-1.fc17.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-3.3.7-1.fc17.x86_64.img
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (12.04) on /dev/sda8
done
```

Then I can reboot as normal and access Windows 7, Fedora and Ubuntu. I was petrified of doing the above but it worked for me without problems to date.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the os-prober package is installed on Fedora, if not install it with
`# yum install os-prober`
Then run `# grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` to update your grub config and Windows should show in the list.

If this doesn't help, make sure you have grub installed on the MBR of the drive you are booting from.

Ref: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same type of problem in my laptop. I installed Windows 7, Fedora 17 and Ubuntu in this order. After installing everything, Ubuntu didn't fetch the Fedora `grub`. I just Google it and found out this helpful [**guide**](http://linuxinternetworks.com/how-to/easy-method-to-update-bootloader-in-linux/).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

i have already install windows 7,ubuntu 12.04 and fedora 17

1 - i have faced the same problem that you have .

2 - so i first remove the easyBCD

3 -  you can add other os in grub so why use easyBD

4 - then i reinstall grub2 of fedora 17 by inserting fedora 17 DVD

```
here is the video of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbxY1WmacG0
```

5 - now fedora grub2 is used to boot all other os

you can also use ubuntu  grub2 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJDcyAncmRY)

fedora grub2 update (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJDcyAncmRY )